# Jugada estratégica

Tags: vocabulario

En el fútbol para una jugada a balón parado, preparada por el equipo, ya sabiendo lo que va a hacer cada uno se dice que es una jugada de estrategia. De acuerdo a las definiciones de táctica y estrategia. A mi me parece que más sentido tiene que sea una jugada táctica. ¿Es correcto utilizar jugada de estrategia en este caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se suele usar

> Jugada ensayada

Aquí tienes el enlace del uso en un periódico deportivo

http://www.marca.com/2012/04/18/futbol/futbol_sala/1334745898.html

Comment: Si lo he oído jugada ensayada y realmente, ahora que lo mencionas, me gusta mucho más. Se me hace tremendo rollo porque a veces lo miro y me parece que es estratégico pero a veces lo veo como táctico. quizás lo correcto sea jugada ensayada. Puede que haya algún argumento para llamarlo estratégico o táctico. Pero aún no me lo aclaro. En ajedrez por ejemplo si puede diferenciarse claramente cuando algo es táctico y cuando algo es estratégico.

Comment: En el fútbol la estrategia y táctica vendría a ser el planteamiento general de un partido (defender en zona, jugar pases cortos, presionar...).

Mientras que una jugada ensayada, es una acción a balón parado, que previamente has entrenado para que salga de una determinada manera (Cuando sacas un corner: centrar al primer palo, Fulanito de cabeza la toca, para que menganito meta gol...)

Comment: aunque no se si lo correcto sería estrategia o tactica si estoy seguro de que estratégia y táctica no son lo mismo como creo entenderte. Creo que para jugada ensayada siempre se usan como sinónimos jugada estratégica.

Comment: Para mi siempre ha sido un poco confuso la diferencia entre estrategia y táctica. Aquí lo tratan de explicar, aunque hay diferentes opiniones sobre el tema:

http://www.luishaba.es/tacticavsestrategia.html

Comment: Buen material. Acepto tus respuestas como válidas.

Answer (score 1):

La estrategia es un plan de juego predeterminado, ideado por el director técnico, mientras que las tácticas son los distintos movimientos y jugadas que tienen a su disposición los jugadores para llevar a cabo dicho plan, que no están predeterminados sino que se eligen de acuerdo a la situación.

Por ejemplo, la estrategia puede ser "formar 4-4-2, mantener posesión, llevarla por los laterales, etc.", y las distintas tácticas son "pases cortitos, contraataque rápido, moverse todos juntos para forzar el offside, etc."

Las jugadas de pizarrón son estratégicas porque las planea el DT antes del partido. No es algo que se les ocurre a los jugadores para realizar la estrategia; es parte de la estrategia en sí, igual que la formación 4-4-2.

Al margen de esto, no tiene sentido decir que el nombre de algo es incorrecto cuando es el que se usa. Si la gente llama “X” a estas jugadas, entonces “X” siempre estará correctamente utilizado para referirse a ellas, ¡porque es su nombre! Podrás o no encontrarle sentido, pero no decir que es incorrecto.

Comment: En español la táctica es el como hacer y la estrategia es el que hacer. En cuanto al idioma y a todo en esta vida el que lo hagan o lo digan millones de personas no quiere decir que sea correcto. En todos los lugares del mundo hay montones de personas que dicen asiéntate y lo  dicen mal. En ningún caso he planteado cambiar el vocabulario técnico sino que me da la impresión de que ese vocabulario técnico ha sido mal formado. Había una tag que era vocabulario técnico sin embargo yo he usado la tag Vocabulario.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar `jugada estratégica`, que creo es lo que buscas.

Comment: Lo tiene puesto en el título ya, precisamente lo que pregunta es si el uso de "estrategia" y derivados es correcto.